# Reflect DataSet update in tablix

Tags: ssrs-tablix

I have a report, and it calls a stored PROC. My dataset was bound to this pulling in (for example) three fields. I have now updated this proc to pull a few more additional fields. I refreshed the DataSet to pull the new fields, and in my "Report Data" window, these changes can be seen. I cannot figure out how to update the Tablix to show the new fields.

The closest I can find anyone referring to this is in threads like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21914345/ssrs-dataset-field-refresh-not-updating-for-tablix), but they all seem to refer to how to update the DataSet. For me, the set has been updated already (via refresh fields), the new fields are not coming through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to see the data from the new columns, you will have to configure the tablix and for example add new columns, groups or something that displays the data of the new columns. The tablix does not include new columns automatically.

Comment: Works. To expand answer. Right click tablix. Add column (left|right). Click empty cell of new column. Click on field name to bind. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction :)